# Как программировать под самодельное устройство?

Tags: c, ассемблер, устройство

Наверняка, каждый из нас слышал про программируемые устройства (чипы), например, на платформе Arduino. Их можно программировать на некоторых языках программирования, например, на C.

Вопрос в следующем: каким образом тот же самый компилятор C способен компилировать C-код именно в тот "вид" Assembler`а, который поддерживает устройство. Это особый компилятор, созданный именно для такого типа устройств, который не поддерживается на обычных ПК? Или же тот C-компилятор компилирует код сразу в массив "единичек и ноликов"?

Основной вопрос: если, допустим, человек у себя дома спаяет с нуля определенное устройство, то как он будет его программировать? Как в его устройство запихать тот же самый Assembler, или еще круче: C ?

Comment: а не должен ли быть у этого устройства процессор? Сам не делал такого, но если на C, то какой-то `execute` файл должен скомпилиться и лежать в памяти устройства.

Comment: Да, естественно, в устройстве есть как минимум одна интегральная схема, оперирующая электрическими импульсами и память, в которую что-то можно положить.

Comment: Как gcc делает код (а обычно используют его)? а очень просто. Так как там есть какой то процессор, то у него должна быть система команд. А раз она есть и компилятор ее знает (программист сам указывает платформу), то можно сгенерировать код.

Приближенно, компилятор вначале создает код на неком общем ассемблере, а потом преобразовывает в заданный.

Comment: @KoVadim, ок, но разве это будет также справедливо для устройства, которое спаяно "на коленке" ? Т.е любая интегральная схема( или группа схем ) должна обязательно поддерживать определенный набор команд?

Comment: абсолютно любая - конечно же нет. Но если там есть процессор, то все может быть.

Comment: Хм, вот как. Тогда возникает побочный вопрос: как примерно в микропроцессор "вбивают" систему команд?

Comment: компилятор генерирует бинарный код. Этот код записывают в ПЗУ (ROM - память только для чтения) или ППЗУ (перепрошиваемое). Грубо говоря - просто флешку. Процессор при старте обращается к нему и начинает читать данные по определенному адресу (это все специфично для каждого процессора) и выполняет потихоньку.

Comment: Самое главное нужно понять, что МК это мини компьютер со всеми возможностями ввода-вывода, обработки и синтезирования сигналов, со своими таймер счетчиками и т.д. В составе одного МК есть все возможности которые(ограниченные конечно) есть у системного блока ПК.

Answer (score 13):

Начнем сначала:

1. То устройство(Arduino), о котором идет речь, работает на микроконтроллерах AVR (чаще всего семейства Mega, которые отличаются друг от друга кол-вом портов ввода вывода, АЦП (иногда ЦАП- но оооочень редко, помоему только начиная с семейства XMega, для них кстати есть также готовые платы Ардуино)). Программа под ардуино пишется на Си, чаще всего, но есть компиляторы Basic, Pascal и т.д.
2. Сразу нужно понять, что для каждого семейства микроконтроллеров существует отдельный компилятор. К примеру для AVR это: AVR GCC(как видно из названия, абсолютно бесплатный), он входит в состав так же бесплатного пакета поставляемого фирмой разработчиком AVR AVR-Studio. На начальном этапе я бы посоветовал CodeVisionAVR, т.к. он позволяет генерировать начальный код на Си, а это куча сэкономленного времени при работе с МК, т.к. иначе придется рыть даташиты и разбираться с регистрами, интерфейсами связи, системами обработки сигналов и т.д. Позволяет сразу задать необходимую тактовую частоту процессора и активировать стандартные таймеры-счетчики. Есть также BascomAVR, MicroBasic, MicroC, MicroPascal и т.д. Но особо следует отметить IAR embedded workbench. На нем при наличии установленных библиотек можно разрабатывать ПО подмикроконтроллеры на ядре: AVR, PIC, PIC32, MSP430, STM32 и ARM(то ядро на котором сидят все Ай и And устройства) писать конечно же на Си(чистый Си, никакого объектно-ориентированного программирования и других мистификаций).
3. Теперь как же он компилирует: при разработке ПО в любом из этих пакетов вы устанавливаете ядро МК, его семейство и конкретную модель, в зависимости от этого сначала создается Асм файл, из которого уже компилятор делает .hex(плюс .coff, .obj и т.д. для работы в эмуляторах типа ISIS Proteus).
4. Теперь главный вопрос, как же запихать полученный .hex файл в МК. 
    а) Вы должны приобрести программатор(для AVR я бы порекомендовал Argussoft AS4)
    б) На Вашей плате должен быть разъем для программирования(интерфейс чаще всего ISP(SPI) или JTAG).
    в) устанавливаете драйвера на ПК от этого программатора и черех его стандартное ПО скидываете Ваш .hex файл на МК.
   P.S. На ардуино программатор не нужен, т.к. у него есть свой бутлоадер и USB шнур!

Comment: Что ж, спасибо! Но вы ведь рассматриваете программирование устройств на базе существующих, а не самодельных.

Comment: Что значит "устройств на базе существующих"? И еще замечание микроконтроллер - это не процессор. Самому изготовить МК невозможно так как - невозможно, другой вопрос что есть ПЛИС МК которые можно запрограммировать так что он поменяет свою структуру.
Если же Вы про программатор, то многие из тех что есть в продаже можно собрать самому. Для этого посмотрите например:
  http://habrahabr.ru/post/128939/

Comment: Да кстати для любителей эклипса есть возможность написания программ под МК в нем:
http://cxemotexnika.org/2010/06/программирование-avr-и-arm-микроконтролле/
Если хотите более подробно изучать программирование МК скачайте ISIS Proteus и в нем собирайте схемы, скидывайте программу одним щелчком и отлаживайте!